# Laravel Shipped with Bitnami WAMP

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie to Laravel so for Composer and NPM,and i know that we need composer and NPM to install laravel and its dependencies.

Bitnami WAMP comes shipped with laravel and after installing Bitnami WAMP and Copying Laravel folder from Bitnami Framework folder to htdocs,laravel worked successfuly (without using or even installing composer), using the command:
`php artisan serve`.

Do I still need Composer,and does this shipped Laravel includes everything ??

Thanks

Comment: you need 'composer' to install or manage any dependency in 'php' language on your project.

Comment: I installed Bitnami before, it provided `php/` for php, `htdoc/` for your app, `apache/` for apache; however, after you clone your laravel in the `htdoc/`, you still need to install the package in laravel. and your php command is in `php/bin/`.

Comment: thats right as i read ,up to the moment i am using laravel shipped with WAMP and i have designed a small web-site with MySQL DB and everything working fine,may be these dependencies i might use them when boarding to Production ?